# Could some one tell me what's are the difference between System.Console.WriteLine and Console.WriteLine?

Tags: c#

Could some one tell me what are the difference between System.Console.WriteLine and Console.WriteLine ?

Comment: Now you have at least two heavily downvoted questions (one deleted by a moderator just now), please make sure you read the Help Centre before asking another one. Too many downvotes will put an automatic block on your account from asking new ones. Questions need to be specific, to do with a programming problem, and should feature should prior effort and research.

Answer (score 3):

System is the namespace that the Console class appears in.

If you have

```
using System;
```

at the top of your file, then you can write Console.WriteLine. If you don't, then you need to write System.Console.WriteLine.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system(v=vs.110).aspx

As was pointed out, if someone created their own Console class that had a WriteLine method, there would be a difference. In this case, using AnotherNamespace; would appear in the code file. Hovering over the word Console in visual studio would normally show you which namespace (can't remember if this does this without resharper.. it's been so long).

So, if you're talking about System.Console.WriteLine in both cases, there's no difference.

;) I don't want to be a liar.

Comment: Yep.  Take out the "using System;" line...and then it won't build.  Then right click the line, and in the context menu there is a way to resolve the reference.

Comment: `There is no difference` is a lie(being pedantic), `Console.WriteLine` could point to `SomeOtherNamespace.Console.WriteLine` other one is not.

Comment: You're right, someone could have implemented a Console class. Considering the question, I was making an assumption on the OPs question.

Comment: @Hammerstein Better not make assumptions on what the OP might be meaning if he asks such a question though.